# xml parsing error with cElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have been writing XML files with cElementTree and when I go to use `.parse(file)` I get an error that says this:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 15
```

The XML file:

```xml
<material Date Created="1/23/2015 at 14:59:10 in Mountain Standard Time" Material Name="Material" Render Engine="CYCLES">
    <main>
        <node0 inputs="" label="" location="<Vector (-114.1876, 479.6438)>" name="Texture Coordinate" node_specific="['from_dupli', False]" outputs="" type="TEX_COORD" />
        <node0 inputs="" label="" location="<Vector (87.1538, 383.3991)>" name="Attribute" node_specific="['attribute_name', '']" outputs="" type="ATTRIBUTE" />
        <node0 inputs="" label="" location="<Vector (-38.2097, 246.6303)>" name="RGB" node_specific="" outputs="[0, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)]" type="RGB" />
    </main>
</material>
```

I don't see why it can't parse a file that it created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse a document that is **not** valid XML. Attribute names cannot have spaces in them, the parser expected an `=` instead of more attribute name:

```xml
<material Date Created="1/23/2015 at 14:59:10 in Mountain Standard Time"
<!--          ^ position 15 on line 1 -->
```

The `<` and `>` characters in the `location` attribute values should also be escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

If you replaced the spaces in the attribute names on the `material` tag and escaped those angle brackets, the document can be parsed:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> sample = '''\
... <material Date_Created="1/23/2015 at 14:59:10 in Mountain Standard Time" Material_Name="Material" Render_Engine="CYCLES">
...     <main>
...         <node0 inputs="" label="" location="&lt;Vector (-114.1876, 479.6438)&gt;" name="Texture Coordinate" node_specific="['from_dupli', False]" outputs="" type="TEX_COORD" />
...         <node0 inputs="" label="" location="&lt;Vector (87.1538, 383.3991)&gt;" name="Attribute" node_specific="['attribute_name', '']" outputs="" type="ATTRIBUTE" />
...         <node0 inputs="" label="" location="&lt;Vector (-38.2097, 246.6303)&gt;" name="RGB" node_specific="" outputs="[0, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)]" type="RGB" />
...     </main>
... </material>
... '''
>>> tree = ElementTree.fromstring(sample)
>>> tree
<Element 'material' at 0x1042d42d0>
```